# Bash script if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, vagrant, puppet, librarian

I'm trying to create a simple bash shell script provisioner for a vagrant puppet dev env which checks that /tmp/puppet-modules-up-to-date exists and was created within a certain timeframe, 14 days to be precise. I'm struggling to progress with this simple script. Any help appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date ]] && [[ ! (find /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date -mtime -14 | grep puppet) ]]; then

    puppet_dir=/etc/puppet

    echo 'Copying Puppetfile into place'
    cp /vagrant/puppet/Puppetfile $puppet_dir

    cd $puppet_dir

    echo 'Installing puppet modules into place'
    librarian-puppet install

    echo 'Updating previously installed puppet modules'
    librarian-puppet update 

    touch /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date
fi
```

Simply gives me the following error:

```
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: expected `)'
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: syntax error near `/tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date'
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: `if [[ ! -f /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date ]] && [[ ! (find /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date -mtime -14 | grep puppet) ]]; then'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be here:

```
[[ ! (find /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date -mtime -14 | grep puppet) ]];
```

Since this is not really catching output of `find/grep` which you could do using `$(find...)` command.

However you can handle this condition better using `grep -q`:

```
find /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date -mtime -14 | grep -vq puppet
```

Comment: Ah yes missed the dollar sign oops... Good solution with inverting the output of grep by the way. Like it.

Comment: Thinking about it I can strip the entire test for the existence of the file as find will pick this up anyway right

Comment: Probably `find` can be used as `find /tmp/.puppet-modules-up-to-date -mtime -14 ! -name '*puppet*'